# How can I select a subset of tuple types and create another tuple from contents of the subset?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a tuple of structs that are defined using variadic arguments:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template<class Type>
struct Pool {
  std::vector<Type> components;
};

template<class... Types>
class Storage {
public:
  std::tuple<Pool<Types>...> pools;

  template<class SelectedType0, class... SelectedTypes>
  std::tuple<std::vector<SelectedTypes>&...> getVectorsFromTuple();

  template<class... SelectedTypes>
  void iterate();
};
```

I want a way to select subset of types from the tuple and create a new tuple that is based on contents of it. Essentially, this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
template<class... Types>
template<class... SelectedTypes>
void Storage<Types...>::iterate() {
  std::tuple<std::vector<SelectedTypes>&...> vectors = getVectorsFromTuple<SelectedTypes...>(pools);
  // getVectorsFromTuple should get the values in the tuple based on types
  // and save reference to each tuple item's structure's `components`
  // property in another tuple 
}
```

One idea that I got for it was to "define" first template parameter in another function  and then use that function to recursively define other parameters:

```
template <class... Types>
template<class SelectedType0, class... SelectedTypes>
inline std::tuple<std::vector<SelectedType0>&, std::vector<SelectedTypes>&...> EntityStorageSparseSet<ComponentTypes...>::getVectorsFromPools() {
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<PickComponent0>(pools).components, getVectorsFromPools<PickComponents...>());
}
```

But I don't know how to unroll/flatten the recursed tuples so this function returns something like:

```
std::tuple<SelectedType0, SelectedType1, ...>
```

instead of

```
std::tuple<SelectedType0, std::tuple<SelectedType1, std::tuple<SelectedType2, ...>>>
```

How can I unroll the tuples or is there a better way to implement what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: The first template declaration does not compile. Can you show a real [mre]?

Comment: Updated all the snippets and they are compiled now: https://ideone.com/w96TBc

Comment: I noticed in your previous question that you said you could do it recursively with templates but wish to do it with folding. If I understood that correctly, you could show the working recursive solution and perhaps someone could make that into a fold expression.

Comment: Ok, now that the picture is more clear, are all `Types` unique, or can they non-unique and if so how to the selection semantics work, because of that. Really, if they're not unique, `std::get` gives you a given type from the tuple, on the silver platter; so this seems to be fairly straightforward to me, at the core.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik They will always be unique. I am even planning on adding a static assertion to make sure that same type is not passed to the class twice (not sure if there is a built in one but that's what I hope to achieve).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was not able to do this recursively either because I don't know how to flatten/unroll the next item in the tuple when creating the tuple recursively.

Comment: So, why doesn't `std::get` work, then? Why would `template<typename ...Types> auto gimme() { return std::tuple{ std::get<Pool<Types>>(pools)...}; }` not work?

Comment: @Gasim Ok, I misunderstood and thought you solved it with recursive templates. If you haven't used them before: `if constexpr (compiletime_condition)` and `sizeof...(variadic_template_type)` (yes, that is `sizeof...`)  are pretty useful to make meta programming almost readable.

Comment: This creates a subset of tuples, which solves one part of the problem but I need to create a tuple from contents of tuple items (pool.components, which is of type `std::vector<Type>`). That's why I was trying to do the recursive function (updated the snippet for the function as it was missing accessing the vector in Pool object, sorry about the confusion).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have this type of recursion in other places where I needed to access the tuple item itself and perform operations. However, I need a way to create a new tuple from my tuple based on contents of the tuple. For example, in the code above, each tuple has a vector named `components`. I want to create a tuple from those components. I don't know what syntax to use to achieve that.

Comment: Doesn't [Sam Varshavchik's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68719504/how-can-i-select-a-subset-of-tuple-types-and-create-another-tuple-from-contents#comment121446573_68719504) work if you use `std::get<Pool<Types>>(pools).components` instead？

Comment: Yes it did work. I just realized that I was setting the `...` in the wrong place (inside the get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following seems to do the job (assuming uniqueness of type in `Types`):

```
template <typename... Types>
template <typename... SelectedTypes>
std::tuple<std::vector<SelectedTypes>&...>
EntityStorageSparseSet<Types...>::getVectorsFromPools()
{
    return { std::get<SelectedTypes>(pools).components... };
}
```